# jQuery slideshow next and previous

Tags: jquery

I've setup started to setup a slide show with next and previous buttons and it doesn't seem to be working. It's not finished but the next and prev buttons should work.

```
    var timer;
    var slides = 5;
    var timeLen = 5000;

    function nextSlide(){
      clearTimeout(timer);
      var current= parseInt($("#counter").html());

      if(current < slides){
          var nextSlide = current + 1;
      } else {
          var nextSlide = 1;
      }

      // set rear image to next slide
      $("#slide_back img").attr("src","http://daduber.com/ss2/" + nextSlide + ".jpg");

      // hide front image
      $("slide_front").animate({opacity: "0"},700,"linear",function(){

      // change front image src(currently hidden)
      $("#slide_front img").attr("src","http://daduber.com/ss2/" + nextSlide + ".jpg");
       $("slide_front").animate( {opacity: "0"}, 700, "linear", function(){
      // display front image
      $("#slide_front").css("opacity","1");

      // change jumpers
      $("#jumpers li.current").removeAttr("class");
      $("#jumpers #" + nextSlide).attr("class","current");

      // update counter
      $("#counter").html(nextSlide);

      // set timer for next image
      timer = setTimeout("nextSlide()", timeLen);

  });

  }

  $(document).ready(function(){
      timer = setTimeout("nextSlide()", timeLen);   
  });
```

[jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/hg2srht3/)

it seems to me its something with the call back function on the animate.
if I replace that with 
$("slide_front").animate( {opacity: "0"}, 700);
it works without the animation

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by changing the animate to:

```
    $("#slide_front").animate(
    {'opacity':'0',
    duration:700, easing:"linear"},
    function(){
```